# How can I make my image and a div with text to always be responsive and the same size?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have an image and a div that go next to each other like this:

[image: here]

Instead it looks like this:

[image: this]

I tried to use flex-shrink and grow and that didn't help. Maybe I should take another approach? Or I am just using flexbox wrong here?

```css
.explore-adoption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-height: 487px;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.explore-info {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 487px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4em;
  background-color: #363635;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 0;
  gap: 1em;
}

.explore-image img {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="explore-adoption">
  <div class="explore-info">
    <h2 class="section-title light">Explore adoption safely and securely</h2>
    <p class="text-content light">Our platforms empower women considering adoprion by providing choice and privacy.</p>
    <!-- ??? -->
    <a href="#" class="section-link light">
      <span>Learn more</span>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="explore-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Birthmother at computer">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Looking better. Now revise to explain why you have max-width and max-height on some elements. What should that do? It's difficult to provide solutions without a clear goal.

Comment: Are you aware that the image will either be distorted or truncated of you enlarge it to the desired size (which has a different width/height relationship than in the first screenshot you posted)? If yes, what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Responsive Font-size

Set the default `font-size` for the page by setting it on the root element (`html` or `:root`). Any lengths set in `rem`s will be relative to the `font-size` (from now on it will be referred to as fs) of root. If the fs of root is 16px (browser default) then a length of 2rem is 32px.

In the example, the fs of root is a relative length: 5vmin. `vmin/vmax` is relative to either the viewport's width or height. If it is `vmin`, then lengths are relative to the smaller length of the current viewport dimensions -- if it is in `vmax`, then lengths are relative to the larger length of the current viewport.

Ex. a viewport width of 800px and height of 450px -- 5vmin means 1rem is 5% of 450px and 5vmax means 1rem is 5% of 800px. Since lengths are relative to viewport, if the browser window changes at anytime, all lengths set in rem recalculates and adjusts accordingly. So if all of the lengths are in rem, you'd have a fully responsive page, but it's not perfect. There will be a point when the ratio of lengths will change when the viewport ratio is flipped from landscape to portrait or if one of the viewport dimensions becomes disappropriately smaller or bigger. That situation is beyond the scope of the question so I'll give you a hint: one solution is media queries.

### Responsive Elements

Set `width` and `height` in percentages.

The parent element that contains both text and image elements should be a flex container and have no padding and margins and hide any vertical overflow (see **Figure I**).

**Figure I** - Parent Element (aka `article.adoption`)

```css
  .adoption {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
```

Next, the right-side element that has the text should be an flex container with a vertical stacking flow. Set it's height to 100% and it's width to 50%. (see **Figure II**)

**Figure II** - Text Element (aka `section.info`)

```css
  .info {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Then on the left-side element that has the `<img>`, set it's height to 100%, width to 50%, remove padding, and hide any vertical overflow. (see **Figure III**)

**Figure III** - Image Element (aka `figure.image`)

```css
  .image {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
```

For the `<img>`, I cropped it so that it's a square using a program: [paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/download.html). Then set `<img>` width to 100%. If there's a small gap at the bottom, add the following ruleset to `figure.image`: `margin: 0 0 -0.5rem 0`. That'll drag the image down and past the bottom border where it'll be hidden by `overflow-y: hidden`.

**View this example in full page mode, dimensions are distorted if viewed in an `<iframe>`**

<sup>Note there's an red dashed outline that shows that the two elements are flush -- this is for demonstration purposes and recommended that you remove the ruleset: `outline: 1px dashed red` from `.adoption`</sup>

```css
html {
  font: 300 5vmin/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

.adoption {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background: #363635;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.info {
  background-color: #363635;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.75rem;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.link {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 -0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<article class="adoption">
  <section class="info">
    <h2 class="title">Explore Adoption Safely &amp; Securely</h2>
    <p>Our platforms empower women considering adoption by providing choice and privacy.</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <span>Learn more </span>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
  </section>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zNPS1z7/mother.jpg" alt="Birthmother at computer">
  </figure>
</article>
```

Comment: I took your approach and it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: Great, don't forget to check the green checkmark to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made each "side" to be 50% width. Also added `align-items: stretch;` to the `flex` to stretch items vertically. Notice: to make it responsive I removed the `max-height`. Also added `height:100%` for the img in case the text makes the left side too high.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.explore-adoption {
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.explore-info {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 4em;
  background-color: #363635;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 0;
  gap: 1em;
}

.explore-image {
  width: 50%;

}

.explore-image img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="explore-adoption">

  <div class="explore-info">
    <h2 class="section-title light">Explore adoption safely and securely</h2>
    <p class="text-content light">Our platforms empower women considering adoprion by providing choice and privacy.</p>
    <!-- ??? -->
    <a href="#" class="section-link light">
      <span>Learn more</span>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="explore-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Birthmother at computer">
  </div>
</section>

<br>
```